# Empty json error when windows suddenly shuts down

Tags: python, json, windows

I think I can express it more clearly. I have some backlog data in my code against reboots. For example, a counter. When the program restarts, the counter should be able to continue where it left off. For this, every time my program runs, I open the backlog.json file and assign the data to the variables in my code. While my program is running, I write my variables to the json file with the help of a timer. So I'm making a backup. No problem so far. After a sudden power outage or system interruption in Windows, my program restarts from startup and tries to get the variables from the backlog.json file. But the json file is empty! But why? Here are the solutions I tried to prevent this situation:

1. Make sure the json file is definitely closed.
2. Copy the backlog json to another file location (example:backlog_copy.json).

I don't even open this copied json at all in my code. Just a copy. But this json is completely empty inside. Before copying the backlog. json file to another location, I also check if it is empty. I think this will be more clear.

## Write json method

`with open('..' , 'w') as myjson: myjson.write('jsonobject')`

How can I fix this situation?

Comment: Is all your code in this `with` block? Also, why would you write your data in an initialize event...does that mean you only write to the file when you start your program? What about ... later ...

Comment: prior to writing a new version of the file, perhaps you might save the existing one as a copy/backup. On restart, if the config file is empty you could try/replace it with the backup.

Comment: Did you try calling [`os.sync()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-sync-method/amp/)? - also, you do have to keep backed-up version because the computer could still be turned off between writing and syncing.

Comment: @topsail Sorry for the narrative. The new explanation may explain it better.

Comment: @JonSG This was exactly my solution. But the json I backed up is also empty. Note : There is a precaution to not backup empty json.

Comment: I think you should probably be checking first of all if the backup is working at runtime. Is your file being updated ... ? For instance, the timer feature may not be working. Or the file may be written with an empty json object because of other bugs in your code. It is important to make sure a file is closed/flushed ... so from your one line of code we also cannot tell if that is happening (all by itself ... probably fine ... but there is surely more code you are leaving out).

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? In any case, opening with `'w'` truncates the file. Writing data doesn't automatically go to disk but might be buffered in RAM, which is lost on power loss. Consider writing the data to a sqlite DB, which can more easily recover from this. Or invest in a UPS. Or use online storage that doesn't suddenly go away.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I understand from your explanation that it has something to do with json. Because isn't it possible to perform operations with the 'w' method in json? I had a UPS. But DB solved my problem. Thank you Ulrich <3

Comment: Sorry, but no, this problem has nothing to do with JSON! What your code does is that it truncates (empties) a file first and then writes new content. If the power is cut in between, you have a truncated (empty) file.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt But I copy the json file to another location with the checking the empty (If json is not empty copy the json to another folder every 10 sec.) So, in your idea is this the reason why the contents of the backup json are deleted?